# Unable to add field on a view

Tags: views, commerce

**I am copying this question from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900553/unable-to-add-field-on-drupal-7-view as I can't see a move option sorry.**

This has been driving me crazy, so let me explain why.

I am building a Drupal 7 site using kickstart commerce, I have been adding fields to the view for checkout, cart and orders fine.

But all of a sudden it seems to do nothing. Let me explain further.

In the edit view page, I click on Add to add the field I want.
[image: In the edit view page, I click on Add to add the field I want]

I then find the field I want to add and then click on 'Add and Configure fields'
[image: add field and configure]

Then normally I would be able to configure the field, however that has now stopped.
Instead I just get the loading symbol [image: loading symbol] and then nothing no configure pop-up or the field added.

I dont understand why this suddenly stopped working, I have cleared the cache and disabled non-required modules, no luck. The fields are configured/added in the same way apart from being different the method they were created in was the same, I have deleted the fields and re-created them still no luck.

Has anyone had this with Drupal 7 or can give me some indication which direction to go in next, thanks in advance.

---

As I stated on the stack overflow question, its not a relationship things as fields configured the same way are able to be added. Existing fields can be removed and added ok.

If I rename to something like test it still fails to add.

I have checked modules that were installed after i noticed the issue, the only one i could see was context disabling this had no effect.

All out of ideas, Google has been no help either :-(

---

A further update to my question I just updated to the latest commerce kickstart(commerce_kickstart-7.x-2.17) and this did not help at all.
The issue still remains.

Comment: Try installing jQuery Update module. Set you admin jQuery for admin pages to 1.7. Views no longer works with the default version bundled with Drupal (1.4.4) nor with versions 1.8+.

Comment: @Bala This project is in the last stages I am just trying to add a few more fields to the view ready for presentation to the customer. Spent about 20 hours so far on this and not wanting to reinstall it if I can avoid it. I have no idea why these will not add.

Comment: @J.Reynolds I installed the jQuery update and set it to 1.7 for admin, left site as default. Still the same issue. I think something is going wrong with the field as existing fields can be removed and added again. The field has been deleted and re-created, then i tried re-creating it with a new name, the same result.

Comment: @Bala Still no joy, so weird. Thanks for your help and advice.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this issue repeatedly and often the only way I have been able to add the missing field/relationship is to export the view, add the new field/relationship in a text editor, and then re-import the view.

Comment: Update: upgrading to Views 7.x-3.13 and Entity Reference 7.x-1.x-dev has fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem on my hosting environment and found out that disabling [SUHOSIN](https://suhosin.org/stories/index.html) php extension solved it.

Do you SUHOSIN on yours?

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the field to a shorter name with [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_rename) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before.

I've solved the issue using shorter field names (It seems that long field names don't work as expected)